# Очистится ли память при наличии обработчика событий в Java?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Объясните, пожалуйста, удалится ли объект при наличия обработчика:

```
public class Util
{
   static void attachHandler(Node node) {
        node.setOnMouseClick(me -> {
            ....
        }
   )};
}

class SomeClass
{
    Node node=new Node();
    public SomeClass() {
       Util.attachHandler(node);
    }
}

class Progr
{
    List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[]args){ 
             list.add(new SomeClass()); // Создан экземпляр SomeClass и обработчик MouseClick для node
             list.remove(0); // Ссылка на экземпляр SomeClass стала недоступна. 
             // А удалился ли обработчик?
             // Не держит ли он ссылку на SomeClass?
             // И зачистит ли все коллектор?
     }
}
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Связь между объектами можно описать так:

```
[ list ] -> [ someClass ] -> [ node ] -> [ me -> {} ]
```

Из этого следует, что удаление любого объекта из представленной цепочки, автоматически приведет к удалению всех объектов рассоложенных справа от удаляемого.

Здесь нет циклических ссылок, ни Node, ни лямбда не содержит ссылок на объект SomeClass, но даже если бы кто-то из них содержал такую ссылку, то GC все равно бы удалил цепочку объектов ссылающихся друг на друга, это отличает GC от Automatic Reference Counting.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.